# Visual Studio 2010: Fatal Error C1902 about "program database manager"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Here's some description from MSDN

> Error Message
>   program database manager mismatch; please check your installation
>   A program database file (.pdb) was created using a newer version of mspdb80.dll than the one found while compiling.
>
> This error usually indicates that mspdbsrv.exe or mspdbcore.dll are
>   missing or have different versions from mspdb80.dll. Ensure matching
>   versions of mspdbsrv.exe, mspdbcore.dll, and mspdb80.dll are installed
>   on your system.

and I want to know what is "program database manager"? And what's the relationship with "mspdbsrv.exe, mspdbcore.dll, and mspdb80.dll"?

Comment: .pdb is the program database. That is the debug file that is used to debug your app.

Comment: So when debugging, mspdbsrv is to dynamicly load mspdbcore and mspdb80?

Comment: If it is your own program, the first attempt would be to delete the .pdb file and let the manager rebuild it. Happens automatically if it is missing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; 
please check your installation
```

If you have kept `mspdb100.dll` in `D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin` folder means this problem will be there. Remove it from the bin folder it is not suppose to be there.

Comment: it didn't work for me...

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem even with an uninstall and reinstall of VS with a Project SLN for the Opus codec.

After hours of searching Google I believe I've found the solution that comes from the accumulation of a number of answers from other forums and sites that did not, by themselves, work.

After an uninstall and reinstall of VS2010 copy the following files from Common7\IDE to VC\bin

```
mspdbsrv.exe
mspdb100.dll
mspdbcore.dll
mspdbst.dll
```

Comment: Tried, did not help me.

Comment: Worked for me - I had first a problem of missing MSPDB100.DLL when trying to use the Windows SDK 7.1 compilers with VS 2019 (need to produce code that targets XP... yes I know we're in 2019...). Copying the PDB DLL made CL start properly but gave the aforementioned error, adding the other files solved it.

Comment: thanks . my problem got resolved through this approach

Answer (score 0):

Cleanly rebuild the project. You will get new exe , pdb and related files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Copy the file mspdbsrv.exe from the VisualStudio/Common7/IDE directory to the /VC/bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all above solution, but none worked for me.

In my case, Jenkins was running with NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user. After changing this to another user, this error was fixed. Hope it's help someone.