# Installation SDK 7.1

Tags: windows, matlab, compilation

I want to ask about an error I faced durring the installation of SDK 7.1 compiler in order to compile .c files under matlab, knowing that I've downloaded SDK ISO and .exe but without use, from this link
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279
I'm using Matlab 2013b,Windows7 64 bit
I got this error every time

Setup could not find the file WinSDK_amd64\WinSDK_amd64.msi at any of the specified source locations G:\Setup

Answer (score 33):

I have an Intel i7, Win 7 64 bit and I was able to resolve this by downloading the Windows SDK 7.1 (iso image) from this link.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/0/F10113F5-B750-4969-A255-274341AC6BCE/GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso

I had tried several downloads and this was the only one that actually contained the ../setup/WinSDK_amd64\WinSDK_amd64.msi  file that the error message references.

Previous to finding this download I had tried removing every single instance of the C++ redistributable for each version of Visual studio I had installed. This alone did not work, because the other Win 7 SDK downloads I tried did not contain the ../setup/WinSDK_amd64\WinSDK_amd64.msi  file that the error message references.

Comment: This worked for me, was finally able to get it to install, thanks

Comment: Had a similar issue, the ISO Image was able to resolve my issue. Thanks

Comment: thanks google, SO and user3620875, and G-d, for sure!
I'm finally able to install this...

Comment: Just installed this successfully to get Windows XP support on Visual Studio 2019 under Windows 10 (about this, see also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531582/1931985)

Answer (score 3):

You can find it using Visual Studio 2019 installer under the name "C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]".

Comment: Noice, this works. The tooltip for this says it includes the 7.1 SDK.